# React Toggle Animation using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

#### Solution:

---

After running console log in useEffect, I could see that it was running on each click re-render so 'click' was not the problem.
The problem was in the CSS `navLinkFade` `@keyframes` animation.
On the initial render, `navLinkFade` is run with `opacity` going from 0 to 1 and `translateX` going from 0 to 50px. This state remains unchanged after initial render.
To fix this I use an `if conditional` and reset `link.style.animation` to `''` if the initial `navLinkFade` animation already exists.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    navlinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 1.5s ease forwards ${
          0.6 + index / 7
        }s`;
      }
    });
  }, [click]);
```

---

#### Original:

I'm currently learning React and am trying to rebuild  a responsive navigation bar from a tutorial that uses vanilla JavaScript.

Everything is working except of the delayed text animation as seen [here](https://youtu.be/gXkqy0b4M5g?t=1906).

I want this delayed text animation to occur when toggling the side panel onto and off of the view screen.

Currently the animation works when the page is refreshed but not when the toggle button is clicked.

I believe the issue is with using the 'click' useState in the useEffect dependency.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jk6op)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';

const NavBar = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    navlinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
    });
  }, [click]);

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <div className='logo'>
          <h4>The Logo</h4>
        </div>
        <ul className={click ? 'nav-links' : 'nav-links nav-active'}>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to='/'
              activeclassname='active'
              className='nav-link'
              onClick={click ? handleClick : null}
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to='/about'
              activeclassname='active'
              className='nav-link'
              onClick={click ? handleClick : null}
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to='/blog'
              activeclassname='active'
              className='nav-link'
              onClick={click ? handleClick : null}
            >
              Blog
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to='/contact'
              activeclassname='active'
              className='nav-link'
              onClick={click ? handleClick : null}
            >
              Contact Us
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div
          className={click ? 'burger' : `burger toggle`}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <div className='line1'></div>
          <div className='line2'></div>
          <div className='line3'></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: make a working example on codesandbox

Comment: onClick={click ? handleClick : null} is wired. i think you should toggle the animation property rather than onClick